# Basic Jquery autocomplete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, autocomplete

The auto complete in my code is not working.

Below is my **HTML** code:

```
<div class="form-group ui-widget">
   <label for="input" class="control-label font-12 font-blue">Enter your Area  <span class="req">*</span></label>
   <input class="form-control ui-autocomplete-input" required="required" placeholder="Enter your Area" name="register[pincode]" id="area">
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var areas = ["States", "Australia", "Indies"];
    $("#register[pincode]").autocomplete({
        source: areas
    });
});
```

Moreover, the html code is being included as a template, if it makes a difference, ideally I think it should not since I am including it in `document.ready` function.

The order the scripts are included is **jquery.min.js** followed by **jquery-ui.min.js** and then bootstrap. The version for **jquery is 2.2.0**

Comment: What do you mean by “not working”? Are there error messages in the [browser console](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525)?

Comment: prepare code in jsfiddle for debugging purpose

Answer (score 2):

With:
`$("#register[pincode]")` You are trying to reference the name attribute as if it were the id. Your element has an id of 'area'. You need to use:

```
$("#area").autocomplete({
    source:areas
});
```

[Jquery id selector docs](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)

If you really wish to use the name you can use:

```
$("input[name='register[pincode]']").autocomplete({
    source:areas
});
```

Note: Don't forget the single quotes around your name value or it will throw errors (well at least it does with [] in the value).

[Attribute selector docs](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$( function() {
    var availableTags = ["States", "Australia", "Indies"]
    $( "#area" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/66bw5u4h/49/)

Comment: Not working still strangely. Just to confirm, there's a modal that opens up and I have to apply autocomplete on that

Comment: Bootstrap modal or UI Dialog?

Comment: It is UI Dialog

Comment: Anshul: still the problem exist?

Comment: used the append to option in autocomplete which solved it. Thank you so much for the concern. :-)